# Module for node.js that works with half-duplex stream?

Tags: node.js, serial-port, hardware

Was using serial-port module on node.js to make a full-duplex data stream (2 wires) between my homemade board and PC and it works perfect and it's easy to use.

I had to make pin reorder due to lack of pins for full project and didn't want to change chip I made half-duplex data stream (1 wire) on board.

Does serial-port work with half-duplex data stream and is there any module that would work?

Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct to describe a single wire shared serial connection as 'half duplex', although the effect is sort of the same. However, the simple answer is: not for RS232. RS485 does do this, but you might have challenges avoiding collisions if either end can transmit at any time.

Comment: Well ok then there is no module, I will make one in this purpose thank You. Well the point of half duplex is waiting for information there is no collision if done well on both sides.

Comment: Yes if one end is always the master and initiates a request and the slave only responds when requested and the master can work out how much data to expect so it doesn't transmit until the slave has finished, then it could work.

Comment: It can work either way, just need to define end and start of information. When one side sends the info it can only wait for info and when it gets info it can only send info. If You want constant stream You can add check bits.